# How to store image folder with many images?

Tags: android

My android app requires over 1000 image icons to show in a image list view. I have all those images in a folder. I want to load all images from that folder and show them in an image list view.

But Drawable folder in Android offer following:
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

I found that there is no way to add a subfolder in any of these folders. Also, if I have to provide different resolution images for all drawable folders which seems complicated for me. I think then the app size will be multiplied by 4-5 times and I will also face difficulty to separate these image files with other images of the app. I think there is a better solution for it? Can you please give any idea about how to achieve it?

Comment: you can use modules in android studio to split your resources in several places.

Comment: How can I do it? Is it some kind of plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with only having one size of the icons you can place them in the resource folder named drawable (without any extra qualifiers). I suggest you use a common naming scheme, like my_icon_XYZ.png, where XYZ is a number starting with 001.

Comment: There is no resource folder, which name is only drawable (without any extra qualifiers). Then?

Comment: Just create a resource folder with the name `drawable` and place the icons there.

Comment: Seems like it will work. I will accept your answer as best answer tomorrow if no better solution comes. Thanks!